# What good homework style tutorials are recommended for learning functional programming in Python?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I recommended to a friend to learn some functional programming using Python to expand his knowledge and overcome programmer's fatigue.

I chose Python because that way there's a good chance he'll be able to use the new knowledge in practical daily work.

I tried to find him some tutorials, and found a lot of guides - diving deep into how to use `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, etc., but don't provide exercises where he can learn while coding.

Where can I find a tutorial that uses functional python to solve problems while teaching?

An optimal answer for me would be homework from a functional programming course, that needs to be written in Python. Such a thing is probably rare because an academic course will usually prefer a purer functional language for such work.

Comment: This book may be somewhat of a beginners book, but it does go into functional programming somewhat and it was originally supposed to be used as a text book for a class. http://pragprog.com/book/gwpy/practical-programming

Comment: "programmer's fatigue"? Like, burnout?

Comment: I'd suggest that if you're learning a new language as a part of learning functional programming, it should be one that's especially good for functional programming.  I'd recommend Scheme, because there's a lot of good material for it.  Languages are easy, and Python especially so; if your friend wants to use Python later on, it can be picked up in no time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe http://diveintopython.net/functional_programming/index.html helps.

Some other useful links are:

- [Functional Programming HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/functional.html)
- [Functional Programming with Python (by Pramode C.E.)](http://linuxgazette.net/109/pramode.html)
- [Functional programming with Python (by CHRISTIAN HARMS)](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/functional-programming-with-python)

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about diveintopython when looking.

Answer (score 1):

I was told about this website when I first started learning. It is a collection of riddles you need to solve using Python. It can be fun.

http://www.pythonchallenge.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a literal answer to your question, but I'd recommend to your friend to practice in Javascript instead of python.  With python you can do some functional programming, but most projects don't need to do much if any.  Javascript really requires doing this, and is at least as common/useful of a language these days.  You'll find a lot more useful educational material on closures in javascript than python.

Comment: Javascript is generally more functional, but it has a lot of pitfalls for the unwary. That's generally why something like Scheme/Racket or Haskell is used.

Comment: Perhaps, but there are about 100x more jobs for javascript programmers than scheme/racket/haskell programmers.

Comment: Right, but languages aren't mutually exclusive. Concepts carry over easily. Learning functional programming can be challenging enough without having to worry about making a Javascript error that the browser isn't reporting. The languages I mentioned tend to yell a lot louder when something is wrong. ;-)